# How can I write a (very) basic custom QAbstractTextDocumentLayout subclass?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a simple notepad-style Qt application. Since I think I might want a lot of control over exactly how text is rendered, I'm trying to write a custom `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout` class. The code below compiles and runs, but the text area is blank, no matter how much I type. The debug statements in my `draw()` function correctly show the entered text, so I know my input is in some form making it all the way to the `draw()` function, but it's not being rendered.

I just want to tweak this in a minimal way so I can at least see *some* text being rendered, even if the implementation is incomplete. I also haven't been able to find any documentation whatsoever on writing custom `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`, so if anyone had a reference I'd also appreciate that.

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QTextEdit>
#include <QKeyEvent>

#include "./DocumentLayout.cpp"

class MainContent : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QTextEdit textEdit;
    DocumentLayout layout;
public:
    MainContent() : textEdit(this), layout(textEdit.document())
    {
        int innerPadding = 20;
        textEdit.document()->setDocumentMargin(innerPadding);

        int textColor = 0xD8DEE9;
        int backgroundColor = 0x2E3440;
        int selectionColor = 0x2E3440;
        int selectionBackgroundColor = 0x81A1C1;

        QPalette palette = textEdit.palette();
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(backgroundColor));
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Text, QColor(textColor));
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Highlight, QColor(selectionBackgroundColor));
        palette.setColor(QPalette::HighlightedText, QColor(selectionColor));
        textEdit.setPalette(palette);

        textEdit.setFrameStyle(QFrame::NoFrame);

        textEdit.document()->setDocumentLayout(&layout);
    };

    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
    {
        textEdit.setGeometry(0, 0, this->width(), this->height());
    }
    
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
    {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_W && event->modifiers() == Qt::ControlModifier)
        {
            qApp->quit();
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowTitle("Hello, world!");
    window.resize(400, 500);

    MainContent content;
    window.setCentralWidget(&content);

    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

`DocumentLayout.cpp`

```cpp
#include <QAbstractTextDocumentLayout>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTextBlock>
#include <QDebug>

class DocumentLayout : public QAbstractTextDocumentLayout
{
public:
    DocumentLayout(QTextDocument *document) : QAbstractTextDocumentLayout(document)
    {
    }

    void draw(QPainter *painter, const PaintContext &context)
    {
        QTextDocument *document = this->document();
        QTextBlock block = document->begin();
        QPointF position(20, 20);

        painter->setPen(context.palette.color(QPalette::Text));
        QTextLayout *layout = block.layout();
        layout->draw(painter, position);
        position.ry() += layout->boundingRect().height();
        qDebug() << "drew" << block.text() << "at" << position;
    }

    int hitTest(const QPointF &point, Qt::HitTestAccuracy accuracy) const
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int pageCount() const
    {
        return 1;
    }

    QSizeF documentSize() const
    {
        return QSizeF(400, 800);
    }

    QRectF frameBoundingRect(QTextFrame *frame) const
    {
        return QRectF(0, 0, 400, 800);
    }

    QRectF blockBoundingRect(const QTextBlock &block) const
    {
        return QRectF(0, 0, 400, 800);
    }

    void documentChanged(int from, int charsRemoved, int charsAdded)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Your question title seems to have nothing to do with your actual question. Please fix one or the other.

Comment: Your `MainContent` class is a bit suspect. Relying on the initialization order in your initialization list is not usually a good idea. For instance, you require `textEdit` to be constructed before `layout`. That in turn is affected by the order in which those are defined in the class (not the order they're specified in the initializer list). So that's a potential future bug. Moreover, make sure that nothing you expect to be non-NULL is actually non-NULL. Qt also expects objects to be allocated with `new`, and it _will_ automatically delete objects within the QObject hierarchy (e.g. `textEdit`)

Comment: @paddy That doesn't sound like the problem because this was working fine without a custom document layout class. But you're saying I should change the fields in `MainContent` to pointers and allocate them in the constructor? (If so, it's still not working after making that change)

Comment: Okay, this is actually kind of funny - it looks like my layout is too big for my window, and Qt is scrolling to the bottom by default. Once I figure it out I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

At least , you need to write the contents of documentChanged.

for example,

```
qreal x, y = documentLeftMargin, documentTopMargin;
qreal width = pageWidth;

for (int bc = 0; bc < document()->blockCount(); bc++)
{

    QTextBlock block = document()->findBlockByNumber(bc);
    
    QTextLayout* layout = block.layout();


    layout->beginLayout();
    while (true)
    {
        QTextLine line = layout->createLine();
        if (line.isValid())
        {
            line.setPosition(QPointF(x + y));
            line.setLineWidth(width);
            
            lineHeight += line.height();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
         }

    }
    layout->endLayout();

}
```

If you read a book in my profil, you can understand completely how to reimplement QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.

https://shisouka6.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=3173&action=edit